# PowerShell script to savestate of VirtualBox VM works but with an error each time

Tags: powershell, virtualbox, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I have written a PowerShell script to start/stop a VM as follows:

`$vma` is the name of the VM.

```
$vmstate = (vboxmanage showvminfo $vma --machinereadable | % { if ($_ -like 'VMState="*"') { $_ } })

Write-Host $vmstate

if ($vmstate -like '*run*') {
    Write-Host "Wait while "$vma" is powered off (saving state)"
    vboxmanage controlvm $vma savestate
}
else {
    Write-Host "Wait while "$vma" is started"
    vboxmanage startvm $vma
}
```

Starting the VM works fine each time. Saving the state works too, but shows this error in the PS ISE output window:

> ```
> Wait while  W2008_21_06_A is powered off (saving state)
> vboxmanage : 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
> At C:\Users\craig\My Documents\vbox.ps1:18 char:5
> +     vboxmanage controlvm $vma savestate
> +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0%...10%...20%....0%...90%...100%:String) [],      RemoteException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
> ```

I get the impression that it has saved the state before VBoxManage has worked out result. Any ideas?

My system specs:

- VBox v5.1.24
- PowerShell v4.0
- Windows 8.1

Answer (score 1):

Your "problem" is, you are using PowerShell in ISE. Try using PowerShell directly. The difference? Two strange things first:

1. When using the `savestate` parameter of `vboxmanage`, the output on success (`0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%`) is written to `stderr` (instead of `stdout`, what would be more appropriate imo).
2. ISE throws an exception, if an external program writes to `stderr`. PowerShell does not do that.

In conclusion, ISE throws an error on an actual success message, because it has been written to `stderr`. You can prevent this behaviour by using the `Start-Process` cmdlet to run external programs. You could replace your calls to VBoxManage.exe by

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" -ArgumentList "controlvm `"$vma`" savestate"
```

and

```
Start-Process "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" -ArgumentList "startvm `"$vma`""
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I edited the script with full paths to vboxmanage and ran from command line with powershell -f  and the error does not occur.

So I guess it is something to do with ISE.

New code:

```
$vmstate = (& "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" showvminfo $vma --machinereadable | % { if ($_ -like 'VMState="*"') { $_ } })

Write-Host $vma $vmstate

if ($vmstate -like '*run*')
{
    # Power off VM before restoring snapshot
    Write-Host "Wait while "$vma" is powered off (saving state)"
    & "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" controlvm $vma savestate
}
else
{
    # Start VM
    Write-Host "Wait while "$vma" is started"
    & "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\vboxmanage.exe" startvm $vma
}
```

On command line:

```
powershell -f "C:\Users\craig\My Documents\vbox.ps1"
```

Don't know if anyone wants to share why ISE would cause the error.

Comment: I added an explanation of the ISE behaviour to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60828394/11942268).